# SharePoint 2016 Templates in VS2015

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2015, sharepoint-2016

New to StackOverflow so sorry if I'm doing this wrong.  Trying to get set up with SharePoint 2016 Development.  Moving from SP2010 and need to look into getting some things updated.  Have a 2016 single server farm set up for evaluation/development and have VS2015 installed on machine, but cannot for the life of me get SP2016 development templates to show up in VS.  I had them briefly after installing the Office Development Tools preview, but after upgrading it to update 2 they're gone again!  Please help.

Also, looking for good information on converting SP2010 projects to SP2016 if that's possible.

Comment: Sorry mate: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam._"

Comment: This is not a question for a recommendation

Answer (score 2):

You need to install: [Microsoft Office Developer Tools Preview 2 for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51683)